# Apache 2.4 Custom 404 Page

Tags: php, windows, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I've looked up many, many, many posts about this but cannot find an answer that works for me..

I've added a `.htaccess` file in `\\SERVER\Apache24\htdocs`, where all of my .php files are (Including 404.php) with only the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

In the `\\SERVER\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf` directory I've changed all instances of `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride all`.

It still serves the default 404 page, not my custom one...

Comment: Try making the change directly in the httpd.conf instead of in the .htaccess file, perhaps it's just not reading the .htaccess file.

Comment: Maybe the syntax on your custom 404 is not right. Show your .htaccess contents. We can't help if you show no code.

Comment: @PanamaJack Literally only `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` is in it. I added the `ErrorDocument` to httpd.conf as well, and changed AllowOverride back to None and it's still working (Even when I remove it from httpd.conf now).

Comment: Have you checked to make sure there's not a conflicting directive in your Apache config?

Comment: Are you restarting apache? You must reload/restart apache after ever config change.

Comment: I'm not sure what did it.. Originally it looked like adding it to httpd.conf is what worked, but I've taken everything out of there and only have stuff in the .htaccess file now and it still works. I think restarting the service might have done it (Network Admin did this for me).